# ASP.Net MVC3: Create custom URL without having the exact controller name in it

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, friendly-url

For a project I've to(unfortunately) match some exact url.

So I thought it will not be a problem, I can use the "MapRoute", to match urls with the desired controller. But I can't make it work.

I've to map this URL:

```
http://{Host}/opc/public-documents/index.html
```

to

```
Area: opc
Controller: Documents
Action: Index
```

Another example is to map

```
http://{Host}/opc/public-documents/{year}/index.html
```

to

```
Area: opc
Controller: Documents
Action:DisplayByYear
Year(Parameter): {year}
```

I tried this, whitout success, in my area(`ocpAreaRegistration.cs`):

```
context.MapRoute("DocumentsIndex", "opc/public-documents/index.html", 
    new {area="opc", controller = "Documents", action = "Index"});
context.MapRoute("DocumentsDisplayByYear", "opc/public-documents/{year}/index.html", 
    new {area="opc", controller = "Documents", action = "Action:DisplayByYear"});
```

But I got some 404 Errors :( when I'm trying to access it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When does ocpAreaRegistration get called? It should be called by `RegisterRoutes` in global.asax.cs

Comment: You can't use the same maproute id for two different routes. Is it like that in the actual code?

Comment: @cellik Sorry for the mapRoute Id, it's only in the example, bad copy-paste

Comment: @podiluska Since it's the file(created by VS2010 when creating the area) which register the default route for the area opc, I guess it should already be called. I tried to put this code directly in Global.asax.cs, but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need to do this (I can only assume you're coming from a legacy application), but this is working for me:

opcAreaRegistration.cs:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "opc_public_year_docs",
        "opc/public-documents/{year}/index.html",
        new { controller = "Documents", action = "DisplayByYear" }
    );

    context.MapRoute(
        "opc_public_docs",
        "opc/public-documents/index.html",
        new { controller = "Documents", action = "Index" }
    );

    context.MapRoute(
        "opc_default",
        "opc/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Controller:

```
public class DocumentsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult DisplayByYear(int year)
    {
        return View(year);
    }
}
```

Make sure you put those routes in the area routing file rather than global.asax and you should be good to go.

Comment: Ouch, I didn't know that the ordre was having some importance and your code point it out! I was having the default route(opc_default) before my custom rule).

Thank you!(and for the reason: It's a federal website, and they discussed during something like two month to define url structure, so I've to use their URL.

Comment: @J4N You're welcome, and that sounds interesting. :)  As for the routing, it does go from specific to general, as you've noticed already.  If you're interested in an example of why that's the case, I posted an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819989/parameters-in-routing-do-not-work-mvc-3/11820201#11820201) to a similar question yesterday that will hopefully help.